# How do I make Drone OSS build anything?

Tags: cicd, drone.io

I have built the Drone OSS using instructions at https://github.com/harness/drone/blob/master/BUILDING_OSS and successfully connected it to GitHub, it is triggering builds and I can log-in to the UI.

However, nothing happens after a build is triggered, the pipeline is stuck in `Loading...` and step does not execute.

Now this is not my first rodeo with Drone, I have the enterprise one running just fine, with runners connected and builds running fine. So I am relatively certain I don't have setup issues.

It is my understanding the OSS one does not support runners, and sure enough when runners try to connect to it they get `404` on the API endpoints they are trying to connect to.

So the question then is, how does one actually build anything with Drone OSS? what pipeline syntax / config must one use?

I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Start server with `DRONE_AGENTS_DISABLED=true`

Source: https://community.harness.io/t/drone-community-not-running-builds/11024/5